# Sample html form with python action flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am working on an html form that has a python action, but cannot find a tutorial that works, so if someone could leave a sample code that would be greatly appreciated. i have tried https://towardsdatascience.com/python-webserver-with-flask-and-raspberry-pi-398423cc6f5d,https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flask-creating-first-simple-application/. i am looking for a hello world type aplication

Comment: Can you elaborate what problems you have with exidsting tutorials and show some of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the tutorial and code samples at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/index.htm to be very handy in learning the basics of Flask.